# SQL split only the numeric values from a varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column with the following values:

```
Column A
------------
001 TestA
002 TestB
003 TestC
```

Now I want only the numeric values from the Column A like:

```
001
002
003
```

Please suggest a solution in SQL

Comment: If the values in the column are consistent i.e. first 3 chars numeric followed by `space`, then you can apply the `substring` function to get the output.

Comment: @dai quick one, how do you get past the "edits must be 6 chars" rule when doing an op like formatting code? Or doesn't it apply to 2k+ rep users?

Comment: @CaiusJard You need more reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that there will always be a space character between the numbers and the text then use `CHARINDEX` with `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING( [Column A], 1, CHARINDEX( ' ', [Column A] ) ) AS Digits
FROM
    myTable
```

Comment: There will always be a space between the numbers and the text. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

1. If you are sure, there will always be 3 digits only then you can go with:

   ```
   Select LEFT([Column A],3)
   ```
2. If numeric digit length is not fixed, but, you will get space between number and digits. In this case you can use:

   ```
   Select LEFT([Column A], CHARINDEX( ' ', [Column A]))
   ```
3. If you want it universal and you are sure you will not value in decimal (Like 123.23). Then, you can go with following;

   ```
   Select LEFT([Column A], PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [Column A]) - 1)
   ```

NOTE: Reply Me if you face any issue in this or out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Using some more troublesome sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#myTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #myTable;
CREATE TABLE #myTable (colA varchar(100));
INSERT #myTable 
VALUES ('001 TestA'),('0002 TestB'),('00003 TestC'),('004TestD!!!'),
('5500599' ),(' 06 TestF'), ('XXX 7 TestG'), ('eight TestH'),(NULL);
```

This would still be simple using [DigitsOnlyEE](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/String+Function/141686/).

```
SELECT * 
FROM #myTable
CROSS APPLY dbo.DigitsOnlyEE(colA);
```

**results**:

```
colA            DigitsOnly
--------------- ----------
001 TestA       001
0002 TestB      0002
00003 TestC     00003
004TestD!!!     004
5500599         5500599
 06 TestF       06
XXX 7 TestG     7
eight TestH     NULL
NULL            NULL
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
WITH myTableCTE AS 
(
  SELECT colA, new = SUBSTRING(colA,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',colA),0),100)
  FROM #myTable
)
SELECT colA, colA_new = SUBSTRING(new,1,COALESCE(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',new),0)-1,100))
FROM myTableCTE;
```

For fun, let's say your column could have multiple numbers like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#myTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #myTable;
CREATE TABLE #myTable (colA varchar(100));
INSERT #myTable 
VALUES ('001 TestA 555'),('0002 TestB 123'),('03 TestC 555'),('[1234][22345][335][44]...');
```

you could use [PatternSplitCM](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/) like this:

```
SELECT colA, item 
FROM #myTable
CROSS APPLY dbo.patternSplitCM(colA, '%[0-9]%')
WHERE [matched] = 1;
```

**results**:

```
colA                       item
-------------------------- -------
001 TestA 555              001
001 TestA 555              555
0002 TestB 123             0002
0002 TestB 123             123
03 TestC 555               03
03 TestC 555               555
[1234][22345][335][44]...  1234
[1234][22345][335][44]...  22345
[1234][22345][335][44]...  335
[1234][22345][335][44]...  44
```

... and, because I'm bored, we'll use PatternSplitCM to pull out possible currency.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#myTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #myTable;
CREATE TABLE #myTable (colA varchar(100));
INSERT #myTable VALUES ('$100,000.00 TestA $5.44'),('$66.22 TestB 12.3456 xxx 333.00');

SELECT colA, item 
FROM #myTable
CROSS APPLY dbo.patternSplitCM(colA, '%[0-9.,$]%')
WHERE [matched] = 1;
```

**results**:

```
colA                              item
--------------------------------- -----------
$100,000.00 TestA $5.44           $100,000.00
$100,000.00 TestA $5.44           $5.44
$66.22 TestB 12.3456 xxx 333.00   $66.22
$66.22 TestB 12.3456 xxx 333.00   12.3456
$66.22 TestB 12.3456 xxx 333.00   333.00
```